# Is wtforms form fields are class objects or functions?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

Using wtforms with flask, I can create object for each field and pass arguments as title and validators list but when adding these objects to the HTML template I can pass CSS class as an argument as well. Can I initialize a class object twice? or the fields are functions?
in the code here:

python:

```
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(),Length(min=2,max=20)])
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
                   {{ form.username.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                   {{ form.username(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
               </div>
```

If username is an object of a class how is it possible to pass arguments to object after constructing and if it is a function how can i access username.label?  I need an explanation as I am new to python (coming from c++).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any object in python can be called as a function as long as it defines a `__call__` method. That method receives the arguments given at invocation (the `**kwargs` syntax below means "collect all non-defined keyword arguments into this dictionary named `kwargs` - keyword arguments are those where the argument name is defined before the value when calling a function):

```
class Foo:
  def __call__(self, **kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

a = Foo()
a(foo="bar")
>>> {'foo': 'bar'}
```

However, the template language offers a bit of help in this case, since you usually can't have a parameter named `class` given directly to a function:

```
>>> a(class="bar")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a(class="bar")
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

You can work around this in pure code by creating a dictionary to hold your function arguments and then expand it to keyword arguments when calling the function (or in this case, the object's `__call__` method):

```
>>> args = {'class': 'bar'}
>>> a(**args)
{'class': 'bar'}
```

Since this only affects the case where the object is called as a function, accessing properties such as `.label` doesn't change anything else.